# how to do a nested foreach loop in yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have this function in my controller:

```
public function actionResource()
{
    $resourcegrporgs = Organization::find()->where(['groupid' => '1'])->all();
    $resmembers = '';
    foreach ($resourcegrporgs as $resourcegrporg) {
        $resmembers = $resourcegrporg->getMembers()->all();
    }
    return $this->render('resource', [
        'resourceMembers' => $resmembers,
        'resourceGroups' => $resourcegrporgs,
    ]);
}
```

and in my view i try to get the members for each group as follows:

```
    <?php foreach ($resourceGroups as $resourceGroup): ?>
<section class="team">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <h4 class="description"><?= $resourceGroup->name ?></h4>
          <div class="row pt-md">
          <?php foreach ($resourceMembers as $resourceMember): ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile">
              <div class="img-box">
                <img src=<?= $resourceMember->picture ?> class="img-responsive">
                <ul class="text-center">
                  <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
                  <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
                </ul>
              </div>
              <h1><?= Html::a(Html::encode($resourceMember->name),['memberdetail', 'id' => $resourceMember->id]) ?></h1>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
            </div>
          <?php endforeach; ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And here is the organization model;

```
class Organization extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'organization';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['name', 'active', 'groupid'], 'required'],
            [['active', 'groupid'], 'integer'],
            [['lastdatemodified'], 'safe'],
            [['name', 'logo', 'userid'], 'string', 'max' => 100]
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'ID',
            'name' => 'Name',
            'logo' => 'Logo',
            'active' => 'Active',
            'userid' => 'Userid',
            'lastdatemodified' => 'Lastdatemodified',
            'groupid' => 'Groupid',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Member::className(), ['organizationid' => 'id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getGroup()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Group::className(), ['id' => 'groupid']);
    }
}
```

However, the `foreach` loop for the members is returning the members of the last group for every other group thus my question:
How can I fix it to render the members of each group individually?

Comment: Why do you have the foreach loop in your Resource action? You are just overwriting that variable each time. When it is passed to your view it's just the last batch of members.

Comment: yeah i noticed that later on...should i rather ommit the foreach at the controller level and just use it in the view?

Comment: i need to find a way to get the members for each group individually...that's why i first thought about the foreach in the resource controller

Comment: Please show the code for your Organization model. I have an idea what it is, but before I fix your code I want to make sure.

Comment: ok..i will edit the  question  and add the organization model to it

Comment: ok here you go...i have added the organization model to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something this is rather easy. Just change your action to the following:

```
public function actionResource()
{
    $resourcegrporgs = Organization::find()->where(['groupid' => '1'])->all();
    return $this->render('resource', [
        'resourceGroups' => $resourcegrporgs,
    ]);
}
```

And then in your view, the inner foreach loop should simply be this:

```
<?php foreach ($resourceGroup->members as $resourceMember): ?>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 profile">
        <div class="img-box">
            <img src=<?= $resourceMember->picture ?> class="img-responsive">
            <ul class="text-center">
                <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></li></a>
                <a href="#"><li><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h1><?= Html::a(Html::encode($resourceMember->name),['memberdetail', 'id' => $resourceMember->id]) ?></h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: thanks a lot...i'm fairly new to yii2 i didn't know it could be done that way...well i really appreciate the help...i was stuck on that for 2 days